# Boxplot from pre-computed statistics is not displaying boxes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I am constructing a boxplot from a data frame with pre-computed statistics (mean, median, lower quartile, upper quartile, 0.1 percentile and 0.9 percentile) using Matplotlib but only the whiskers are displayed.

```
boxes = []
for i in df.index:
    box = {
            'label': i,
            'mean': df.loc[i, 'Mean'],
            'q1': df.loc[i, 'LQ'],  
            'med': df.loc[i, 'Median'],       
            'q3': df.loc[i, 'UQ'],  
            'whislo': df.loc[i, '0.1 Percentile'],  
            'whishi': df.loc[i, '0.9 Percentile']
            }
    boxes.append(box)
ax.bxp(boxes, meanline=True, showfliers=False)
plt.show()
```

The figure produced:
[image]
Please could you help me display the boxes in addition to the whiskers.

Comment: Without knowing how your data looks like, it is hard to guess what is going wrong. Could you show the output of `print(boxes)`?  And the plot you got? And explain how it differs from the expected result? Possibly your values are strings instead of numeric?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `print(boxes)` shows [{'label': 1, 'mean': 31.639491526246466, 'whislo': 32.0, 'q1': 32.0, 'med': 32.0, 'q3': 32.0, 'whishi': 32.0}, {'label': 2, 'mean': 31.61800278766012, 'whislo': 32.0, 'q1': 32.0, 'med': 32.0, 'q3': 32.0, 'whishi': 32.0}, {'label': 3, 'mean': 35.66454209023232, 'whislo': 32.0, 'q1': 37.0, 'med': 37.0, 'q3': 37.0, 'whishi': 37.0}...] for the first 3 boxes in `boxes`.

Comment: Your q1, median and q3 are the same value. This makes their box shrink to a line.  It is very weird that you have a mean outside the range between whislo and whishi.   You probably need to revise how your data are calculated. A q1 and q3 both of 32 means 50% of the data is equal to 32. The box goes from q1 to q3 with a dividing line at the median.

Comment: @JohanC Ah yes, I completely forgot to check the data! Thanks for your help!